# preprocess_page if front

Tags: theming

I have a preprocess_page function that applys classes to my content if there is a sidebar or not.

```
  if ($vars['page']['sidebar']) {
    $vars['content_classes'] = 'cool-class';
  }

  else {
    $vars['content_classes'] = 'super-cool-class';
  }
```

Can I do a similar with adding class if its the front_page. I want it to be included into this one but I do not seem to find the right way to do it.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add both condition for **sidebar** and **front page** like this.

```
if (drupal_is_front_page() && $vars['page']['sidebar']) {
      $vars['content_classes'] = 'cool-class';
}

else {
      $vars['content_classes'] = 'super-cool-class';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [drupal_is_front_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7) function.

Something like :

```
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
  $vars['content_classes'] = 'front-page-class';
}
else {
  $vars['content_classes'] = 'normal-page-class';
}
```